# Blowfish passwords indirectly saved through a separate Model method do not work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, blowfish, cakephp-2.7

The following does work:

```
// app/Controller/UsersController.php
$this->User->save(array('pwd'=>$new_pwd),false);
```

The following does not work:

```
// app/Controller/UsersController.php
$this->User->setPassword($new_pwd);
```

The `User` model has the `beforeSave()` which works and the custom method `setPassword()` that does not:

```
// app/Model/User.php
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'])&&!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'])) {
        $new_password = $this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'];
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'] = $passwordHasher->hash($new_password);
    }
    return true;
}

public function setPassword($new_password) {
    $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
    $result = $this->save(array(
        'pwd' => $passwordHasher->hash($new_password),
    ), false);
    return $result;
}
```

So the `setPassword()` is more or less identical yet whenever I try to log in with the password saved that way, `$this->Auth->login()` returns false. I can see the password hash updated in the database though.

Am I missing something? Please help

Comment: Doesn't your setPassword internaly also call beforeSave() via save()? Thus, logically from looking at it only seconds it becomes pretty clear that you are hashing it twice then, making it impossible to be used anymore.

Comment: @mark Thank you, you're right, that's what the problem was. I guess I just needed someone else to look at this. Please post this as an answer so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPassword()` internally also calls `beforeSave()` via `save()`.
It becomes pretty clear that you are hashing it twice then, making it impossible to be used anymore.

Comment: Tip: I am using the [Passwordable](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) behavior to only activate the hashing part when intended, I find this cleaner, more DRY and less error prone than the automated beforeSave() approach.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance, and for suggesting the new approach!